# Getting some crashing error reports from google play console

Tags: android, react-native, crash, google-play-console

I am using react native 64.0.3 version target sdk version 31. Getting this error from play console like this. Any solution? It is happening from recent update that I uploaded to the play store yesterday. Here is my crash report details:

```
 1)Type
        java.lang.NoSuchMethodError
        Exception java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
          at f.c.h.a.a.c.f
          at f.c.h.a.a.c.e
          at com.facebook.react.modules.fresco.FrescoModule.initialize
          at com.facebook.react.bridge.ModuleHolder.doInitialize
          at com.facebook.react.bridge.ModuleHolder.markInitializable
          at com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeModuleRegistry.notifyJSInstanceInitialized
          at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl$2.run
          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:751)
          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:95)
          at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage
          at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:154)
          at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run
          at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:762)
2)Type

com.facebook.react.common.c

Exception com.facebook.react.common.c:
  at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ExceptionsManagerModule.reportException (ExceptionsManagerModule.java)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
  at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke (JavaMethodWrapper.java)
  at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke (JavaModuleWrapper.java)
  at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run (NativeRunnable.java)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:938)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:99)
  at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage (MessageQueueThreadHandler.java)
  at android.os.Looper.loopOnce (Looper.java:238)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:349)
  at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run (MessageQueueThreadImpl.java)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:920)
```

Comment: Please Add crash stacktrace as text not image .